# Video not falling back on Android Email client

Tags: android, email, video

I have foolishly agreed to add video to a clients email campaign. The road has been smoother than expected until I started testing android email clients.

**The issue:**

The video does not look like it is supported but the client attempts to load it anway resulting in the gross grey box pictured in the following:

[image]

**My markup:**

```
<a href="http://evoke.digital360.com.au?showVideo=1" class="video-link" style="box-sizing: border-box; color: #1f1f1f; background-size: cover; display: block; width: 540px; height: 300px; background: url('images/launch-video.gif') no-repeat center center;">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="video" poster="images/launch-video.gif" controls="controls" width: 540px; height: 300px;">
            <source src="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/latrobe-health/launch.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <img src="images/launch-video.gif" alt="a promotional evoke video" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 100%; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border: 0 none;" />
    </video>
</a>
```

I have wrapped the element in an a tag so when people click on the video it will take them off to the site to learn more about the company (the controls of the player still function as normal).

Why is this not falling back to the gif I have as a fallback? Are there any tricks to get this to fallback as expected?

**What I have tried:**

The grey box only appears when I attempt to play the video. I had a thought that I could set a background image to the wrapping a tag of the same fallback but it doesn't show, I just get a white box with the player controls, no background.

Any ideas as to a workaround? I have searched high and low for a fix on this, so far nothing has worked.

Comment: OS version/device you are testing on

Comment: I am on a Note3 running 4.4.2